# Fair Coin Winnings

Tags: probability

I believe this is a fairly simple question but am unsure as to what the correct approach is.

> Suppose you flip a fair coin and bet ${$}x$. If heads comes up, you win ${$}.9x$ ; if tails comes up, you lose ${$}x$. You have ${$}10,000$ and you need to win at least ${$}5,000$. What is the likelihood of winning at least ${$}5,000$ with a single bet? What is the likelihood of winning at least ${$}1,000$ by playing 10,000 times and o only betting ${$}1$ each time? What is the likelihood of not losing money?

My confusion arises as to what probability I’m supposed to use. The ‘fair’ probably since it’s a fair coin, or the dealers implied probability based on the winnnings and loses?

Comment: The coin is fair (probability $\frac12$ of heads and similarly tails) but the payments are not.  So if you want to win $\$5000$ you will have to bet more than that

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of the question, it's a single bet, meaning that you bet all $10,000$ dollars, and you either win $0.9 * 10000 = 9000$ dollars or you lose $10,000$ dollars. There's 2 outcomes with equal probability and only in one of them you make at least $5,000$ dollars.

For the second and third part of the question, you're doing $10,000$ flips with a bet of one dollar one each. Each trial is still a flip on a fair coin, so there's a 50% chance you make 90 cents and a 50% chance you lose the dollar. In this way, you can think of it as a binomial distribution with 10,000 trials and P(Success) of 0.5. You can also calculate n, the number of trials you need to win to make at least 1,000 dollars and move on from there.

Answer (score 1):

You must risk $5000/.9$ to win $5000,$ but your odds of winning are $50\%$ since it's a fair coin.

For the other you must compute what fraction of flips you need to win to walk away up $1000.$ Then the probability of winning at least that number with a fair coin can be computed, perhaps using a Gaussian approximation.

(Actually, provided I've done the math right, the answer is so tiny the first platform I tried couldn't distinguish it from zero. And it is so far into the tail that the Gaussian approximation becomes a bit iffy. I suppose this only serves to underline the point of the exercise.)