# Cumulative probability with different weights on results

Tags: probability

I'm just learning probabilities and have some questions, I recently read Richard Thaler's book on behavioral finance and it offered a question similar to below, I'm uncertain how to calculate it.

Given the bet:

- 50% chance to earn $2
- 50% chance of losing $1.

If you could guarantee playing this game 3 times, what is your probability of making money?

---

If the question was "what's the likelihood of 3 heads in a row", I would simply do:

.5^3 = .125

If I draw out every possible scenario (8 of them):

```
2 2 2
2 2 -1
2 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1
-1 2 -1
-1 2 2
2 -1 2
-1 -1 2
```

4 of them indicate I make money, 1 indicates I lose money, and 3 of them come out even.

How do I calculate the 4 of them? What would the formula be?

EDIT: This question illustrates a similar problem but don't really explain how the calculation would be done:
[Fair Coin Winnings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2627369/fair-coin-winnings)

EDIT 2: Clarification on above, I am looking for a formula to apply so that I can change numbers, i.e. if I did this 20 times instead of 3 times, what is my probability of making money?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. Are you thinking that the 8 scenarios have different probabilities? If so, why?

Comment: You have done the difficult part of the calculation.  Since each of your possibilities have the same probability of $\frac18$ of happening, you have a probability of $\frac48=\frac12$ of making money and $\frac38$ of breaking even and $\frac18$ of losing money

Comment: @Henry -- but I just did it manually, how would I calculate this. let's say I did it 20 times? Or 100 times?

Comment: @ChrisCulter I think there's a 50% probability of making money, a 37.5% probability of coming out even, and a 12.5% probability of losing money. I had to count this out, I don't know what formula could be used to do the same thing if I raised this to something higher?

Comment: @KerryJones Oh, then you want https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function . In your case $p=1/2$, which simplifies things a bit, and the threshold $k$ is some function of the winnings, which you can compute.

Comment: You have in effect a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ games and $p=\frac12$ and you want the probability of winning more than $\frac n3$ of the games.  So the probability is $1 - \frac{1}{2^n}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/3\rfloor}{n \choose i}$

Comment: If either of you want to write that as an answer below, I think that's what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: So I've looked into this pretty thoroughly but I'm still not understanding of how to determine the actual number... Could someone write it out with the example that will equal the 50%? As far as I can tell Binomial Distribute will calculate the exact odds of getting certain amount of picks based off probability-- but I'm looking to calculate "greater than 0", i.e. make profit, where the odds are 50% for either scenario, but the value is weighted

Comment: Looking into this further, I don't think this is binomial distribution, because there are 3 outcomes: made money, came out even, lost money. This would violate the definition of a binomial variable